# Trouble Installing New Version of Perl Using Perlbrew

Tags: perl, gcc, solaris, cpan, perlbrew

So based on instructions I was given on stackoverflow, I was attempting to install a new version of Perl on my 64 bit Solaris virtual machine using perlbrew, in order to ultimately install 'cpanm' and install the CGI and DBI modules, as well as the DBD::Oracle driver. These are the steps I was following:

1) Open up a terminal window and login as the **root** user. Then install the following packages...

- `pkg install system/header`

  `pkg install gcc-45`

  `pkg install developer/build/gnu-make`

  `pkg install archiver/gnu-tar`

2) Install perlbrew...

- `curl -kL http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash`

3) Next, open up ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile and append the following line of code..

- `vi ~/.bash_profile` **OR** vi `~/.profile`

  append `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` to the end of the file

  log out of root

  log back into root

  Additionally, you may have to manually source the file by entering: `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` if the next few steps do not seem to work.

4) Begin to install the new Perl.

- `echo $PERLBREW_ROOT` --> this should equal /home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew

  `perlbrew -v install perl-5.16.0 -Dcc=gcc`

**Output From Installation:**

```
Test Summary Report
    -------------------
    ../cpan/CGI/t/tmpdir.t                                          (Wstat: 0 Tests: 9 Failed: 0)
      TODO passed:   3, 6, 8
    ../cpan/Socket/t/getnameinfo.t                                  (Wstat: 256 Tests: 14 Failed: 1)
      Failed test:  10
      Non-zero exit status: 1
    Files=2334, Tests=522101, 1212 wallclock secs (90.50 usr 58.34 sys + 533.70 cusr 288.26 csys = 970.80 CPU)
    Result: FAIL
    *** Error code 1
    make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `test_harness'
    Installed /home/oracle/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.16.0 as perl-5.16.0 successfully. Run the following command to switch to it.

      perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
```

- `perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0`

However, when I try to switch to the new perl, it says: `perl-5.16.0 is not installed`.

So I did a `ls $PERLBREW_ROOT` and found it contains a **bin, build, build.log, Config.pm, dists, etc**, and **perls** directory. And thus I figure the new Perl should be installed in the **perls** directory, but doing an `ls $PERLBREW_ROOT/perls` shows that there is nothing in the **perls** directory. Does anyone have any idea what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It misreports it as being installed when it fails due to test failures. If you believe the test failure is acceptable, you run it again skipping the tests:

```
perlbrew -v install perl-5.16.0 --notest -Dcc=gcc
                                ^^^^^^^^
```

---

This is the test that is failing:

```
my $expect_host = gethostbyaddr( inet_aton( "127.0.0.1" ), AF_INET );
defined $expect_host or $expect_host = "127.0.0.1";
( $err, $host, $service ) = getnameinfo( pack_sockaddr_in( 80, inet_aton( "127.0.0.1" ) ), NI_NUMERICSERV );
is( $host, $expect_host, "\$host is $expect_host for NS" );
```

If you scroll up in your log output, you'll see the values you actually got for `$host` and `$expect_host`.

Comment: So that did seem to work, and there does seem to be a perl-5.16.0 in the **perls** directory now. However, when I go to install the DBI module using: `cpanm -v DBI` it still fails. I put the output in the OP.

Comment: For better results, start a new question

Comment: Haha, seems like I'm starting an endless array of questions. I was just trying to keep it less cluttered, but if that's your suggestion, will do.

Comment: You're question will get more exposure, and figuring out what is a reply to what will be simpler.

Comment: You'll need to provide way more info than you that which posted. We have no idea which tests failed and for what reason, so we can't help you address the failures.

Comment: Just made a new thread. Will try posting more of the error code as well.

Comment: @ikegame Question, where would I find more of the error though? I can't seem to gather too much info from the actual terminal screen, and I looked in the build.log but there seems to be no relevant information there either.

Comment: "Installing DBI failed. See /home/oracle/.cpanm/build.log for details."

Comment: Right, I looked in there, but there wasn't any real error messages other than the same `FAIL
! Installing DBI failed. See /home/oracle/.cpanm/build.log for details.`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `cpanm`. If you use `cpan DBI` instead, the output will be output to the terminal.